# Scaling of plot in ggsave() different when RStudio plot pane is active

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, rstudio

I cannot provide a reproducible example for this, but I wanted to ask about a curious behavior of the `ggsave()` function: I am experiencing the following:

1. I create a ggplot, by assigning a plot to a variable, let's say `p`
2. I evaluate `p` and - as it should be - the plot is displayed in the plot pane of RStudio.
3. My next call is `ggsave(plot = p, filename = "plot.pdf")`, the plot is
   written to plot.pdf and R gives me the dimensions of the written plot on the console.

The strange thing is: When the RStudio plot pane is active (i.e. a RStudio graphics device is open), the dimensions of the plot written by `ggsave()` in step 3 are different than when no RStudio graphics device is open. Consequently, the scalings of the written plot are off. In other words: Step 3 produces different results depending on the execution of step 2. Does anyone know why this is the case? I thought that `ggsave()` is totally independent of any RStudio device. Or does this only happen on my machine?

This is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.1     scales_0.4.1      data.table_1.10.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] ggrepel_0.6.12     Rcpp_0.12.12       digest_0.6.12      grid_3.4.1         plyr_1.8.4         gtable_0.2.0       rlang_0.1.2        lazyeval_0.2.0    
 [9] labeling_0.3       RColorBrewer_1.1-2 tools_3.4.1        munsell_0.4.3      compiler_3.4.1     colorspace_1.3-2   sciplot_1.1-1      tibble_1.3.3
```

Comment: From `ggsave()` documentation 'width, height Plot size in units ("in", "cm", or "mm"). If not supplied, uses the size of current graphics device.'

Comment: Aaah! Thanks a lot ... I didn't read the documentation thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on Andrey Kolyadin's comment above...

> From ggsave() documentation 'width, height Plot size in units ("in",
>   "cm", or "mm"). If not supplied, uses the size of current graphics
>   device.'

If we dig into the code behind `ggsave`, there's a snippet that says:

```
if (any(is.na(dim))) {
  if (length(grDevices::dev.list()) == 0) {
    default_dim <- c(7, 7)
  }
  else {
    default_dim <- grDevices::dev.size() * scale
  }
...
```

Which means that if the dimensions are not specified by the user:

1. if there's no active graphics device at all, default dimensions are 7 x 7;
2. if there's at least one active graphics device, use the dimensions of the last one (multiplied by `scale`, which defaults to 1).

RStudio's plot pane is a graphics device. So `ggsave`'s behaviour differs depending on whether there's anything there.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on the above comment. It totally makes sense!